# Localization issue in Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have a very strange issues while playing with app localization in metro applications. In my app launched function i have registered app language change event.

```
ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValues_MapChanged;

private void QualifierValues_MapChanged(IObservableMap<string, string> sender, IMapChangedEventArgs<string> @event)
    {
        ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.Reset();
    }
```

I have `ComboBox` control which contains languages. When ever user select any of language, i have override default language as shown.

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo((string)((ComboBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Tag);
```

This works fine and call MapChanged event in Windows 8.1 but when i test the same app in Windows 8.0 it does not work properly. I have debug this issue and found that MapChanged event does not fire sometimes when `PrimaryLanguageOverride` change and sometime it fire. Is this is issue with windows or i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please give me a reason for down voting.

Answer (score 0):

The resource context works a bit differently in Windows 8.1 due to support for multiple views.   Instead of DefaultContext, you should use the context returned by ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().   You'll want to save the context in a static or instance variable so that it doesn't pass out of scope.  So:

```
class MyClass {
    private ResourceContext m_context;

    public MyClass()
    {
        m_context = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
        m_context.QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValues_MapChanged();
    }
    ...
}
```

Typed by hand so apologies for any typos.

Answer (score 0):

The MapChanged event occurs on a thread other than the user interface thread, so you have to do something like the following, in order to make sure the UI thread is used:

```
ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged += async (s, m) =>
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.Reset();
        // other update code like myLabel.Text = ...
    });
};
```

where Dispatcher is the current page's Dispatcher property for example.